# CSS background-position: animating and performance

Tags: css, animation, background-position

I've seen many examples for animating the background-position of elements to produce nice looking scrolling backgrounds.

These examples tend to also script in reset counters to put the background-position in its original location after a certain amount of pixels.

My question is: Is it feasible to never reset the background-position for a tiled background? This would naturally produce very large background-position values over time, but if there is no significant difference in browser performance, it might be ok. I've tested IE, Firefox, and Chrome over an 8 hour period, and there didn't appear to be any negative impact, although my boxes are relatively fast.

To answer the "why not reset?" question, it just comes down to simplicity. I am animating many background elements, each with different X/Y ratios, so not having to calculate when exactly it would be pixel perfect timing to switch back would make my life easier.

Anyone have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This would naturally produce very large background-position values over time

Yes, that could eventually become a problem if your code is like

```
el.style.backgroundPosition= '0 '+n+'px';
```

When n reaches a high number (typically 1000000000000000000000), its `toString` will switch to exponential representation, which would end up trying to set:

```
el.style.backgroundPosition= '0 1e21px';
```

which is an obvious error. It's possible some layout engines might bail out earlier, perhaps at 1<<31 pixels. But even so, if you were animating something by (say) 32 pixels 60 times a second, it would still take twelve days to reach that stage.

> not having to calculate when exactly it would be pixel perfect timing to switch back would make my life easier.

Typically you'd use the modulo operator `%` separately on each counter rather than resetting the whole thing.

```
var framen1= 30;     // item 1 has 30 frames of animation
var framen2= 50;     // item 2 has 50 frames of animation
    ...
var framei1= (framei1+1)%framen1; // 0 to 29 then reset
var framei2= (framei2+1)%framen2; // 0 to 49 then reset
```

Or, for time-based animations:

```
var frametime1= 100; // item 1 updates 10 times a second
var frametime2= 40;  // item 2 updates 25 times a second
    ...

var dt= new Date()-t0; // get time since started animation

var framei1= Math.floor(dt/frametime1) % framen1;
var framei2= Math.floor(dt/framelength2) % numberofframes2;

document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundPosition= '0 '+(framei1*24)+'px';
document.getElementById('div2').style.backgroundPosition= '0 '+(framei2*24)+'px';
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would hit an overflow of some sort, but if you tested it over an 8 hour period, it is unlikely that it is possible to get the browser to overflow. It is just speculation.